# Lucene: what are the hits for the query?

Tags: java, lucene

I've just seen in [1](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_1/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/TopDocs.html#scoreDocs) totalHits and scoreHits return the top and total number of hits for the query respectively.

What does "hit" mean exactly ? Is it the position of the searched term in a document, or the documents in which the term is included... or what ?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The totalHits is the number of documents that matched the query. A hit is essentially a match for the query you entered.  However a hit may be a partial match or a full match

e.g. If we use Lucene to index over a set of 3 texts: { “hello world”, “hello sailor”, “goodnight moon” }, then searching for: hello world

total hits: 2

1.078 hello world

0.181 hello sailor

The float value indicates the score for the hit, which is the relevance to the query string.

The following post gives more details https://web.archive.org/web/20110228/http://lingpipe-blog.com/2009/02/18/lucene-24-in-60-seconds/

Comment: ok, however totalHits is still a bit confusing. It is a method of the class TopDocs, which are the top relevant docs (in my case I've set the limit to 20 docs. TopDocs docs = searcher.search(query, 20); So totalHits should be always 20... ?!

Comment: @Patrick, totalHits will only be 20 if there are 20 actual hits. What you have done is limit the totalHits to 20 in the case where there are more than 20 actual matches.